# Ajax jquery autocomplete from mysql database, flask framework

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, flask, autocomplete

Hello I am following this tutorial 
http://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/flask-framework-ajax-autocomplete/ 
to autocomplete a couple of textboxes through mysql database. However this tutorial shows how to autocomplete only 1 textbox in a pretty static way. I need my website to have more than 1 textboxes and getting the autocomplete options from different tables of the database. Instead of having jquery code and @app.routes for each textbox individually i would like to make this code dynamic to handle all queries from the different textboxes to the different tables in the database.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is definitely possible, but I'm not sure exactly what your question is or what you're having trouble with.

I would note, however, that the example has you inserting arbitrary user-submitted strings directly into an SQL query which is incredibly insecure: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

I would recommend making use of some Python library to help with your database usage - SQLAlchemy (via [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/)) is probably the most common and certainly one of the best.

Comment: Peter thank you for your answer. For my project I need to have dropdown textboxes that autocomplete through my database. In this tutorial it shows you how to connect to the database and everything but when i try to add a second textbox i have trouble querying the corresponding table. I could add another @app.route to get the arguments but since there is going to be a lot of textboxes in the website so it does not scale well. I've seen the sqlalchemy docs  but did not see an explicit solution to such an easy and common task.

Comment: Well you can pass more than one item in a form. You could for example set the form name to 'country' or whatever else to signify which query you want. Then in flask you could use query_name = request.form['name'] and query = request.form['query']. Then you pass query_name and query to some function which looks up the correct query for you.